# Maven Repo That Generates .so File, use as dependency in Maven Project

Tags: java, android, maven, android-ndk, .so

Hell All,

First of all I am working with Android and I have some questions about the maven build process when it comes to automating the use of native libraries in my Android project. I say automating since currently I can take the native project (repo) and build the .so file that I need (through maven build process) then I just copy that .so file and put it in my main projects native libs folder (i.e. mainProject/src/main/libs/armeabi-v7a/nativeLib.so). So... my native project pom.xml that kicks out the .so file looks like the following (build area)

```
<packaging>so</packaging>
<properties>
    <android.ndk.args>V=1 -B NDK_DEBUG=1 -j8</android.ndk.args>
    <arch>armeabi-v7a</arch>
    <mavenAntrunPluginVersion>1.8</mavenAntrunPluginVersion>
</properties>

<build>

    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-webdav</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${mavenAntrunPluginVersion}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <exec
                                    dir="${project.basedir}/src/main/java/com/abc/myClass"
                                    executable="javac"
                                    failonerror="true">
                                <arg value="myClass.java"/>
                            </exec>
                            <exec
                                    dir="${project.basedir}"
                                    executable="javah"
                                    failonerror="true">
                                <arg value="-d"/>
                                <arg value="${project.basedir}/target/jni/include"/>
                                <arg value="-classpath"/>
                                <arg value="${project.basedir}/src/main/java"/>
                                <arg value="com.abc.myClass.MyClass"/>
                            </exec>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>

            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-ndk-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <target>${project.artifactId}</target>
                <finalLibraryName>${project.artifactId}</finalLibraryName>
                <ndkPath>${android.ndk.path}</ndkPath>
                <applicationMakefile>src/main/cpp/Application.mk</applicationMakefile>
                <makefile>src/main/cpp/Android.mk</makefile>
                <architectures>${arch}</architectures>
                <additionalCommandline>${android.ndk.args}</additionalCommandline>
                <librariesOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/ndk-libs</librariesOutputDirectory>
                <objectsOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/ndk-obj</objectsOutputDirectory>
                <headerFilesDirectives>
                    <headerFilesDirective>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/cpp</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**\/*.hpp</include>
                        </includes>
                    </headerFilesDirective>
                </headerFilesDirectives>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So this throws the .so into the myNativeProject/target/ndk-obj/armeabi-v7a/nativeLib.so. I then usually copy this over to my main project. I try making this project a dependency with the type .so but it doesn't recognize it. How do I add this into my main project? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using a `SNAPSHOT` version of the [android-ndk-maven-plugin](http://simpligility.github.io/android-ndk-maven-plugin/). I would suggest to use the newer release version.

Comment: Will do, I can still build the project. Just need to know how to point my main project over to this .so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright,

So basically in the .so project I utilized the 'build-helper-maven-plugin' to attach my .so artifact. Then in my main project I used the 'maven-dependency-plugin' to copy (goal set to copy) the .so file over to the native output directory. Please comment if anyone requires more information.